# How to get row sum for multiple rows?

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

I am trying to change the cells under B column to blue if the sum for the corresponding row is less than 55000. Below is my code I have figured out to achieve that for one row. How could I modify it so that it works for the other rows if I have a lot of rows?

```
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim result As Long

    Set rng = Sheets(2).Range("C2:N2")

    result = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(rng)
    
    If result < 550000 Then
        Sheet2.Range("B2").Font.Color = vbBlue
        Sheet2.Range("B2").Font.Bold = True
    End If
```

Comment: You could use conditional formatting for this... is VBA necessary?

Comment: Yes I want to do it strictly with VBA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a loop:

```
With Sheet2
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        If Application.Sum(.Range("C" & i & ":N" & i)) < 550000 Then
            .Cells(i, "B").Font.Color = vbBlue
            .Cells(i, "B").Font.Bold = True
        End If
    Next
End With
```

**EDIT**:
If you want to do the same thing, but for columns instead of rows:

```
With Sheet2
    Dim lastColumn As Long
    lastColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToRight).Column

    For i = 3 To lastColumn
        If Application.Sum(.Columns(i)) < 550000 Then
            .Cells(1, i).Font.Color = vbBlue
            .Cells(1, i).Font.Bold = True
        End If
    Next
End With
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Just a follow-up question, what if I wanted to do the same except now I want to do the sum for the columns instead of rows and make the color changes to the month labels on top?

Comment: You would loop the columns instead of the rows but the approach would be similar.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried the following but it does not work, what could I modify to make it work? Sorry I am fairly new to VBA. 
```    
With Sheet2
    Dim last_column As Long
        last_column = .Cells(.Columns.Count, "C:N").End(xlToRight).Column
        
        Dim i2 As Long
        For i2 = 2 To last_column
            If Application.Sum(.Range("C" & i2)) > 1850000 Then
                .Cells(i2, "C:N").Font.Color = vbGreen
            End If
        Next
        End With
    ```

Comment: Also avoid string math and replace `.Range("C" & i & ":N" & i)` with `.Range("C2").Offset(i-2,0).Resize(1,12)`. This starts with a base address "C2", moves down by `i-2`, and references 1 row and 12 columns.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou - I see no issue in the hard-coded `N`. There's no "string math" going on there, and the range in question is quite apparent with each iteration of the loop. I would wager that your proposed approach is unnecessarily more complicated.